# Losing information from CSV spreadsheets following multiple runs

Tags: python

I am trying to edit some information from my spreadsheet. I run my code once, and it works, I run this code a couple more times and it still works. Then on about the 5th or 6th go at running the code, All of the information within the spreadsheet disappears. My code is as follows:

```
    rotashiftlengthmondaycsvread = open("Program/LengthDays/Monday.csv", "r")
    rotashiftlengthmondayread = csv.reader(rotashiftlengthmondaycsvread)

    data = []
    for item in rotashiftlengthmondayread:
        if item != '':
            data.append(item)

    itemdataloop = 0
    for item in data:
        if item[0] in openingmonday:
            item[1] = lengthofshiftopening[itemdataloop]
            itemdataloop += 1
            print(data)

    rotashiftlengthmondaycsvwrite = open("Program/LengthDays/Monday.csv", "w", newline = "")
    rotashiftlengthmondaywrite = csv.writer(rotashiftlengthmondaycsvwrite)

    rotashiftlengthmonday = []
    for item in data:
        rotashiftlengthmondaywrite.writerow(item)
        rotashiftlengthmonday.append(item)
```

UPDATE:
It seems to be an array within an array.

Comment: Try using `with open` instead of `open`. Its much safer and opening the file without closing it might be the reason why your spreadsheet is getting erased. `with open` will automatically close your file.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't closing the file after you open it, so I suspect that's the problem. If a file isn't closed, there is no guarantee the file buffer is actually written and saved to disk.

The following should work

```
rotashiftlengthmondaycsvread = open("Program/LengthDays/Monday.csv", "r")
rotashiftlengthmondayread = csv.reader(rotashiftlengthmondaycsvread)

data = []
for item in rotashiftlengthmondayread:
    if item != '':
        data.append(item)

itemdataloop = 0
for item in data:
    if item[0] in openingmonday:
        item[1] = lengthofshiftopening[itemdataloop]
        itemdataloop += 1
        print(data)
rotashiftlengthmondaycsvread.close() # close the file

rotashiftlengthmondaycsvwrite = open("Program/LengthDays/Monday.csv", "w", newline = "")
rotashiftlengthmondaywrite = csv.writer(rotashiftlengthmondaycsvwrite)

rotashiftlengthmonday = []
for item in data:
    rotashiftlengthmondaywrite.writerow(item)
    rotashiftlengthmonday.append(item)
rotashiftlengthmondaycsvwrite.close() # close the file
```

However, I recommend the `with` construct which, for files, will guarantee the file is closed *even* if some Exception is raised while the file is open. See below

```
with open("Program/LengthDays/Monday.csv", "r") as rotashiftlengthmondaycsvread
    rotashiftlengthmondayread = csv.reader(rotashiftlengthmondaycsvread)

    data = []
    for item in rotashiftlengthmondayread:
        if item != '':
            data.append(item)

    itemdataloop = 0
    for item in data:
        if item[0] in openingmonday:
            item[1] = lengthofshiftopening[itemdataloop]
            itemdataloop += 1
            print(data)
# file closes here on exiting the "with" block


with open("Program/LengthDays/Monday.csv", "w", newline = "") as rotashiftlengthmondaycsvwrite
    rotashiftlengthmondaywrite = csv.writer(rotashiftlengthmondaycsvwrite)

    rotashiftlengthmonday = []
    for item in data:
        rotashiftlengthmondaywrite.writerow(item)
        rotashiftlengthmonday.append(item)
# file closes here on exiting the "with" block
```

Here is some expanded basic information:
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python
And some more general information about `with`:
https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html